# What connector is similar to U.FL but has no pin?

Tags: rf, connector, identification, wifi

I am trying to identify this connector style:

[image]

Look at the two RF micro-coax connectors on the left, just next to the PCB antennas.  They look identical to U.FL or IPEX but have no central pin.  What are these, and what are they used for?

This is what U.FL looks like for a comparison:

[image]

Comment: They look like they have sockets.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it looks like its a small dimple, not a longer pin like the U.FL connector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a special switched connector for testing or using external antennas.  Notice that there is a trace on both sides of the connector, but only one side on the u.fl connector.  When you plug a test connector into the jack, it actually disconnects the signal flowing through it and routes it out the test connector instead.  They show up all the time in wireless routers and the like because they can be used to perform accurate tests on the radio with the antenna disconnected before it ships.  They can also be used to add an external antenna to a device by bypassing the internal antenna.  This is one series of this type of connector:

http://www.ttiinc.com/object/Murata-Switch-Connectors-HSC-RF-Coaxial.html

Comment: So it's a Wireless/RF compatible test point for antenna pogo pins. Neat. Nice catch.

Comment: Yeah, these things are all over the place.  My cell phone has 3 of them.  I didn't think of pogo pins though - that does make perfect sense.  The black insulator on the ones in my phone is beveled like a funnel to help guide the pin into the center.  Most RF connectors aren't designed like that, but it makes perfect sense for guiding a pogo pin into the connector.

Answer (score 2):

Hirose produce these too, see their catalogue page, you can see the beveled funnel a little bit clearer on these colour photos (page 4) :  http://www.hirose.co.jp/cataloge_hp/e35801678.pdf