# Can you help me identify the antenna? Looking to add External Antenna

Tags: antenna, board

[image]I'm looking to add an external antenna and I want to find out I add the antenna using a Mini PCI U.FL to RP-SMA Antenna WiFi Cable Signal Connector Network Adapter I got off of ebay to a Trendnet Range Extender.  I'm a total newb and need help identifying what #1 is, what #2 is, and really what else I might need to know to get this working.  Thanks!!!![image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1I8B.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

1 is a ceramic chip antenna ([Datasheet/App note for similar/generic chip antenna](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra092b/swra092b.pdf)). Instead of a wire or pcb trace antenna (or some other type), a chip antenna allows a manufacturer to avoid lengthy testing by using a 3rd party dedicated part.

2 looks like a u.fl connector, but the picture is blurry, can't be sure.

**Update**: Another question has the answer to the connector. It's a switched connector. See the answer to [What connector is similar to U.FL but has no pin?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/88041/what-connector-is-similar-to-u-fl-but-has-no-pin)

Comment: You will likely need to desolder/remove one of the series capacitors between the connector and the chip antenna, but not sure.

Comment: It doesn't exactly look like a u.fl connector in the sense that it doesn't appear to be a male.  It looks like a female connector of sorts.  Added another picture, still blurry but closer up.  This may be a dumb question, can i solder the cable i'm getting to the chip, or right next to/touching the chip antenna?

Comment: Instead of the chip, yes. Google image search `external antenna mod` for literally hundreds of examples of that. Good luck @silvebemr

Comment: http://www.m0mcx.co.uk/gallery/galleries/Antenna_Experiments/Huawei_E220_External_Antenna_Modification/Dsc_7164.jpg

Comment: That's a close up of on an example of what i have on my board.  When you say instead of the chip does that mean i should remove the chip or just add it next to it.  And this is my very first attempt at something like this.  So i get i'm asking for annoying detail but it's because i really don't know.

Comment: Having two antenna elements will introduce problems. Typically when someone does this, they remove the on board one, or cut a trace to remove it from the circuit.

Comment: so if i cut the trace to the antenna chip, do i solder a new female u.fl right on that trace?

Comment: I have no personal experience in that, so if you break it you've been warned I'm not at fault, but yes.

Comment: It is not a u.fl connector, it is some sort of switched test connector, hard to say exactly which one.

Comment: @passerby a u.fl connector can have a switch in it. The  circuit design certainly suggests so.

Comment: @tomnexus A u.fl connector has a pin in it, nor can it have a switch. This connector has a "socket" instead of a pin and a built-in interrupt switch. Hence it is certainly not u.fl.

Comment: you got it.  there is no pin.  I'm trying to determine exactly the game plan.  If I can/should solder the wire i'm getting directly to the line going to the antenna.  or do you remove the antenna chip and add the antenna there?

Comment: @silverbemr updated. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/88041/what-connector-is-similar-to-u-fl-but-has-no-pin for the connector type.